# How to parse xml into a table with sibling elements?

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, lxml

I have xml that looks like this:

```
xml = """
<portfolio>
    <assets>600000</assets>
    <assetClassDetails>
        <assetClassName>Bonds</assetClassName>
        <assetAmount>100000</assetAmount>
    </assetClassDetails>
    <assetClassDetails>
        <assetClassName>Equities</assetClassName>
        <assetAmount>500000</assetAmount>
    </assetClassDetails>
    <rateOfReturn>6.3</rateOfReturn>
</portfolio>
"""
```

I am parsing every element into a table, by doing this:

```
root = etree.fromstring(xml)

tag = []
text = []
parent = []
double_parent = []

for element in root.iter():
    try:
        element_parent = element.getparent().tag
    except AttributeError:
        element_parent = 'none'
    try:
        element_double_parent = element.getparent().getparent().tag
    except AttributeError:
        element_double_parent = 'none'
    tag.append(element.tag)
    text.append(element.text)
    parent.append(element_parent)
    double_parent.append(element_double_parent)

df = pd.DataFrame({'tag' : tag, 'text' : text, 'parent' : parent, 'double_parent' : double_parent})
```

This results in this:

```
tag                 text      parent            double_parent
portfolio           \n        none              none
assets              600000    portfolio         none
assetClassDetails   \n        portfolio         none
assetClassName      Bonds     assetClassDetails portfolio
assetAmount         100000    assetClassDetails portfolio
assetClassDetails   \n        portfolio         none
assetClassName      Equities  assetClassDetails portfolio
assetAmount         500000    assetClassDetails portfolio
rateOfReturn        6.3       portfolio         none
```

I am struggling with how to pivot the data so that the asset class name and amount are paired up and tied to the portfolio tag (and its immediate children). How do I get pair up sibling tags in the results?

My desired result looks like this:

```
type        assets  rateOfReturn    assetClassName  assetAmount
portfolio   600000  6.3             Bonds           100000
portfolio   600000  6.3             Equities        500000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
rows = []
columns = ['assets',  'rateOfReturn',    'assetClassName',  'assetAmount']
for entry in root.xpath('//assetClassDetails'):
    row = []
    row.extend([entry.xpath('preceding-sibling::assets/text()')[0],
                entry.xpath('following-sibling::rateOfReturn/text()')[0],
                entry.xpath('./assetClassName/text()')[0],
                entry.xpath('./assetAmount/text()')[0]])
    rows.append(row)
pd.DataFrame(rows,columns=columns)
```

Output:

```
    assets  rateOfReturn    assetClassName  assetAmount
0   600000  6.3     Bonds   100000
1   600000  6.3     Equities    500000
```

Another interesting way to do it by using another library:

```
import pandas_read_xml as pdx
df1 = pdx.read_xml(r'path\to\myfile.xml',['portfolio','assetClassDetails'])
df2 = pdx.read_xml(r'path\to\myfile.xml',['portfolio'])
pd.concat([df2[['assets','rateOfReturn']],df1], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
assets     rateOfReturn assetClassName  assetAmount
0   600000  6.3         Bonds             100000
1   600000  6.3         Equities        500000
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way of using the package @JackFleeting mentioned could be:

```py
import pandas_read_xml as pdx
from pandas_read_xml import fully_flatten

df = (pdx.read_xml(r'path\to\myfile.xml', ['portfolio'])
      .pipe(fully_flatten))
```

The flattening expands lists (sibling tags in XML) into separate rows, or dictionaries (sub tags in XML) into separate columns.

Comment: Interesting! Wasn't aware of `fully_flatten`.

Answer (score 0):

below (not using any external library)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = """
<portfolio>
    <assets>600000</assets>
    <assetClassDetails>
        <assetClassName>Bonds</assetClassName>
        <assetAmount>100000</assetAmount>
    </assetClassDetails>
    <assetClassDetails>
        <assetClassName>Equities</assetClassName>
        <assetAmount>500000</assetAmount>
    </assetClassDetails>
    <rateOfReturn>6.3</rateOfReturn>
</portfolio>
"""
data = []
root = ET.fromstring(xml)
global_properties = {'assets': root.find('assets').text, 'rateOfReturn': root.find('rateOfReturn').text,
                     'type': root.tag}
for asset in root.findall('.//assetClassDetails'):
    entry = {x.tag: x.text for x in list(asset)}
    for k, v in global_properties.items():
        entry[k] = v
    data.append(entry)
for entry in data:
    print(entry)
```

output

```
{'assetClassName': 'Bonds', 'assetAmount': '100000', 'assets': '600000', 'rateOfReturn': '6.3', 'type': 'portfolio'}
{'assetClassName': 'Equities', 'assetAmount': '500000', 'assets': '600000', 'rateOfReturn': '6.3', 'type': 'portfolio'}
```